# Yahoo api switch to oAuth from public data javascript

Tags: javascript, api, yahoo

I've been using a public API and now need to increase the limit, hence need to switch to oAuth according to yahoo documentation.

How do I switch this to work with oAuth, all the example I've found are other than javascript/jquery.

I've been using ajax and the code is in the form -

```
var query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = " + "'" + symbol + "'";

var yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + escape(query) + "&format=json&diagnostics=false&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?";

$.ajax({
url: yql,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) { ......
```

Any pointers would help a great deal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a fair bit of research on this today. I've come to the conclusion Yahoo! hasn't provided Client Credentials (2-legged) flow in their implementation of OAuth2 (see [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) in the specs).

I'm basing this on if I try to POST to https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token using grant_type = client_credentials, I get an ERROR_HANDLING_REQUEST.

If you'd like, Yahoo!'s implementation of OAuth1 is still up and running. I don't think I'm going to go this route. Who knows how much longer it'll be up and running. However, I found this blog article really helpful, [Authenticating to Yahoo Public API’S with OAuth](http://westbrook.co.uk/authenticating-to-yahoo-public-apis-with-oauth/). There are some Yahoo! gotchas involved in this approach (see Hoop 1 **Important** section and Hoop 2 OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET + '%26' code comment).